# Java: Receiving an UDP datgram packet with multiple DatagramSockets

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I am trying to implement a method that sends an UDP packet to multiple receivers. I thought that this should be doable setting `setReuseAddress(true)` on the receiving DatagramSocket instances.

My problem is that in certain conditions I need to limit the communication to the local computer - hence the localhost interface (useLocalhost=true in the demo code below). In such a case suddenly only the first receiver socket gets the incoming packet, the two other don't see anything.

I tested this on Windows (oracle 64bit) and Linux (OpenJDK 64bit), therefore I only see three possibilities:

1. This is an intended and known behavior (and I don't understand the whole mechanism - aka "bug in my brain")
2. There is a bug in the Java JRE
3. There is a bug in my code.

### **Does somebody have any experience on that topic and can me help to identify where the problem is located?**

See below a minimal working example that demonstrates this. **Note that I am using the broadcast address for simulating network packets that come from a real external host.**

If everything goes right you should see three lines at the end (in this or a different order):

```
Thread-0 - packet received
Thread-1 - packet received
Thread-2 - packet received
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    boolean useLocalhost = true;

    InetSocketAddress addr;
    String sendPacketTo = "192.168.1.255"; // we use broadcast so that packet comes from an real external address
    if (useLocalhost)
        sendPacketTo = "localhost"; // does not work (only listener 1 received packet)

    addr = new InetSocketAddress(15002);

    new MyThread(addr).start(); // Datagram socket listener 1
    new MyThread(addr).start(); // Datagram socket listener 2
    new MyThread(addr).start(); // Datagram socket listener 3

    DatagramSocket so = new DatagramSocket();
    so.setBroadcast(true); // does not change anything
    so.connect(new InetSocketAddress(sendPacketTo, 15002));
    so.send(new DatagramPacket("test".getBytes(), 4));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.exit(0);
}

public static class MyThread extends Thread {

    DatagramSocket socket;

    public MyThread(InetSocketAddress addr) throws SocketException {
        super();
        setDaemon(true);
        socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.setBroadcast(true); // does not change anything
        socket.bind(addr);
        System.out.println("Listener started: " + socket.getLocalAddress());
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buf = new byte[10];
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(p);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - packet received");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is sort of trying to do broadcast, sort of trying to do multicast, and sort of trying to do unicast. Pick a model and stick to it! For example, if you're trying to do broadcast, use a broadcast address.

Comment: @David: Please read my comments. The broadcast address is only used for simulating incoming traffic. Otherwise my example would be much more complicated because of th second program that needs to be run on a second PC.

Comment: @Robert so if this isn't your real code why post it?

Comment: It is a minimum working example demonstrating the problem and my question.

Answer (score 1):

192.168.1.255 is a broadcast address, so the datagram is broadcast, under the rules for UDP broadcast. 127.0.0.1 is a unicast address, so the packet is unicast. So you get different behaviour.

As @DavidSchwartz commented, your code is a mixture. Connecting to a broadcast address for example doesn't have a lot of meaning, and neither does binding to it. I think what you are looking for is multicast.

Comment: The purpose of my question was to understand why reusing a Datagram socket does work for incoming external traffic but fails for traffic on localhost. Therefore answers like yours do not help me much. Furthermore Multicast is not an option at all in this situation as it can not be limited to localhost AFAIK.

Comment: The purpose of my answer was to point out that when you use broadcast in one case and unicast in another case, you are not necessarily entitled to expect the same behaviour, and that attributing the different behaviour to the use of localhost rather than switching to unicast is irrational. Shame you didn't get it first time around. You are also incorrect in your assertion that multicast cannot be limited to the localhost. That's what the TTL is for, and there are also host-local multicast addresses.

Comment: You drew my attention onto multicast, therefore I made some experiments. However I wasn't able to find any references regarding the "host-local multicast addresses". Setting the ttl to 0 works on local host only but uses a public IP address. According to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879046/how-to-limit-traffic-using-multicast-over-localhost) it is not possible to use multicast on localhost.

Comment: The answers in that question are mistaken. You can use the TTL field to limit the scope of multicasts. The details can be found in W.R. Stevens as quoted in my new answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multicast on localhost
However, there are several things you need to be careful of to make it work.

example: 
lo0 (127.0.0.1)
en0 (192.168.0.111)
en1 (10.1.0.111)

1. for each interface 2 separate sockets, one for receiving, one for
   sending.    In the above example this means creating a total of 6
   sockets.
2. Never bind() a socket that will **send** multicast UDP packets.
3. Always bind() a socket that will **receive** multicast UDP packets.
   Never try to setsockopt() or reconfigure multicast sockets after you call bind()
   Instead, when machine's interfaces change due to cables being unplugged/plugged,
   destroy all send/receive multicast sockets and recreate them.

sample code:
iMulticastSocketInterfaceIPAddress would be one of the three interfaces

```
     /* use setsockopt() to request that the kernel join a multicast group */
     struct ip_mreq mreq;
     mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr=inet_addr( "239.192.0.133" );
     myAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr;         
     mreq.imr_interface.s_addr=( htonl(iMulticastSocketInterfaceIPAddress) );
     theErr = setsockopt( CFSocketGetNative( mSocketBroadcast ) ,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,&mreq,sizeof(mreq));
```