# Java UDP DatagramSocket stops receiving

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have a DatagramSocket where I'm receiving in a loop and it eventually just stops receiving packets. I send the server a hello message that establishes the connection. Then I start reciving packets as expected. Eventually it just stops receiving.

The sending server has verified that they are still sending packets to the same address via tcp dump but eventually this code hangs on the receive call.

Is there anything that would cause the socket to stop receiving?

```
String hello = "hello";
InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("serveraddress");

DatagramPacket outboundPacket = new DatagramPacket(hello.getBytes(),hello.getBytes().length, IPAddress, 54321 );
DatagramSocket registerSocket = new DatagramSocket(61646);
registerSocket.send(outboundPacket);
int count = 0;
while(!done){

    count++;
    byte[] inboundData = new byte[1368];
    DatagramPacket inboundPacket = new DatagramPacket(inboundData,inboundData.length);

    System.out.println(registerSocket.getPort());
    System.out.println(registerSocket.getLocalPort());

//Eventually locks up here after hundreds of successful receives
    registerSocket.receive(inboundPacket);

    byte[] data = inboundPacket.getData();
    String test = new String(data, "ISO-8859-1");
    System.out.println(test+"---"+count);
}

registerSocket.close();
```

Comment: are you sure its not crashing

Comment: Certain. The process continues to run, no exceptions thrown and it for sure stops on registerSocket.receive(inboundPacket);

Comment: Are you behind NAT? If so, it is probably timing out the mapping due to lack of outbound activity.

Comment: Didn't even occur to me but that must be the case. Could be that my comcast modem is acting as a nat given my IP address. I'll look at my nat timeout settings. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That was it. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're behind NAT, the mapping will time out if there's no outbound traffic for too long. Make sure to send an outbound datagram every few minutes to keep the mapping active in the router.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from the question, whether you work with several DatagramSockets inside one process: This would be non-trivial. See [Java: Receiving an UDP datagram packet with multiple DatagramSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20890046/9437799)

Unless using multicast, a newly created datagram socket will inherit the process' receiving cursor and clamp
the existing one from receiving.