# How to get UDP pub/sub to work on mac osx?

Tags: python, macos, sockets, udp

I've got a simple pub/sub system that works on linux using UDP sockets, but doesn't work on Mac OS X (specifically 10.10.3).  Is there something I can change to allow it to work on my mac?

pub.py:

```
import sys
import socket
sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sender.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line: break
    sender.sendto(line,("127.255.255.255",4321))
```

sub.py:

```
import sys
import socket
receiver = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
receiver.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
receiver.bind(('',4321))
while True:
    data,addr = receiver.recvfrom(1500)
    sys.stdout.write(data)
```

To run it I start multiple instances of sub.py in separate windows.  In one window I start pub.py and type stuff into stdin (pressing return), and it shows up on both recipients.  It works on a recent versions of Linux Mint and Centos.

Comment: Adding receiver.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1) to the sub.py and setting the send-to address in pub.py to 192.168.0.255 works on my mac, but sending lots of traffic through that address slows down my network.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `127.255.255.255`. `127.0.0.1` works fine.

Mac OS X's loopback interface [doesn't support broadcasts](https://serverfault.com/questions/554503/how-do-i-add-a-broadcast-ip-to-the-loopback-interface-under-os-x-using-ifconfig).

Comment: The link you cited also states that Linux doesn't support broadcasts and yet the sample code works there.   (To be fair, the loopback interface doesn't advertise a broadcast capabilities.)  Switching to 127.0.0.1 results in the message only showing up on one recipient.

Comment: @DarinMcGill There's Python localhost/multicast code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879046/how-to-limit-traffic-using-multicast-over-localhost).